# Cocos2d-x v3.7.1 Unfortunately, libcocos2dx has stopped

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm compiling a new project through proj.android-studio using:

```
cocos compile -p android --android-studio
```

But when I start app on android device, it shows me a message:

> Unfortunately, libcocos2dx has stopped

Can you help me? What I'm doing wrong?

Here is logcat:

> 09-07 12:07:47.711  23074-23074/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: org.cocos2dx.TestGame, PID: 23074
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "srand" referenced by "libcocos2dcpp.so"...
>               at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
>               at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:553)
>               at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:288)
>               at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:303)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the app stops working if your code contains errors.

Are there errors in your code? What does the LogCat say?

Comment: It is a NEW HELLO WORLD project. It must work properly

Comment: And you don't get any LogCat errors? A NullPointerException or something like that?